# Angular toggle boolean variable from sibling components located inside an ngFor

Tags: angular, boolean, toggle

The case is as follows, an ngFor renders a collection of components (app-item). Each component has a boolean variable named "open" and a function named "toggle" that toggles (true or false) the variable.

How can I click the button of a component (app-item) and change the state of the remaining iterated sibling items?

**app-page.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <app-item [data]="item"></app-item>
</div>
```

**app-item.component.html**

```
<button (click)="toggle($event)">Toggle "open" variable.</button>
<div *ngIf="open">Content is now visible</div>
```

**app-item.component.ts**

```
export class ItemComponent {    
  open: boolean = false;

  toggle(event: any) {
     this.open = !this.open;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have 3 options

- use `@Output()` in app-item-component and emit an event to parent component then change all component state by `@Input()` set
- use a service and create a subject inside it and subscribe in child components
- add a property field to your item model as boolean and change it by refrence in child or parent components